# How to move up & down in repeater control list?

Tags: jquery

I have bind repeater control list like ul li

i need to display users first 5 names first.when user click down arrow it will move down and get next five names.like other all name.if again move up it need to display previous 5 names.

same time my focus[selected name] height should be in always center name for ex

1
2
3(selected) background color some think 
4
5

down arrow

6
7
8(selected) background color some think 
9
10

like all the name.

how to do this in jquery or code behind

Here is a repeater example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="carouselDeptItem_<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1  %>">
           <%#Eval("Name") %>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```